# C# .net core application doesn't create log file when executed thru Powershell, but creates log file when executed thru Command Line or Visual Studio

Tags: c#, powershell, log4net

I have a .net core 5.0 console app with log4net 2.0.12.Upon execution, from visual studio or from command line after publish, log file generated successfully. When the same published app is executed thru PowerShell, app executes as expected but log file does not get generated.

```
> $CLI_HOME= "C:\PowerShellDemoDeployment\PowerShellDemo\"
 $CLI = "PowerShellDemo.exe"
 $COMMAND = $CLI_HOME + $CLI 
 "Command being executed: " + $COMMAND
  Invoke-Expression $COMMAND


 namespace PowerShellDemo
 {
  class Program
   {
    static ILog logforLoader = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
       
        logforLoader.Info("Process started at :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Started...Going to Sleep for some time");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("Woke up ...finishing... ");
        logforLoader.Info("Process Completed at :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to diagnose the problem. Please also read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @mklement0 - I completely agree.  Q: How can we *GET* more information?  Any suggestions for troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: @paulsm4, well there's the gold standard of a [mcve], but that would be nontrivial in this case. I'd start with at least showing the invocation command line and any specific failure symptoms (quiet no-op? is an error reported?) and discussing potential variations in the invocation environments (different working directories? is the log file created with a relative path?)

Comment: @Sudipta Ghosh: Q: Is "successful execute" (MSVS or CLI) always on your workstation?  Are you successfully able to execute from the cmd line on other environments, besides your workstation?  Q: Can you show us the Powershell script? Please "edit" your post, and copy/paste the script.  Q: Can you reproduce the problem with an [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)?

Comment: @paulsm4, quick tip: If you use `[edit]` (without code formatting) in a comment, it turns into a link that edits the question at hand; e.g. [edit]; see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting for other handy shorthand links.

Comment: Even on the Server, when the application will be running, using CLI, it executes normally with out any error/issue. The only problem is the log file is not generated.

Comment: `new FileInfo("log4net.config"))` : As @mklement0 as already mentioned, this is using relative path and so will only work if log4net.config is in the current directory and probably needs to be something like `new FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) , "log4net.config")) `